# Alternative to AndroidMediaLibary

Tags: android, performance

I’m creating a music player in java and use the `AndroidMediaLibary`.
Are there some alternatives to this with a better performance? I have to load a lot of songs and that needs about 3sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with NDK, try ffmpeg. It is best lib to deal with audio and video. You need to work in c or c++ to handle background work.
Link is below.

[FFmpeg is a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)

OR if you are familiar with **Java** only. Just go for **[JAVACV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/)**. It is Java wrapper on  famous c/c++ libraries eg OpenCV, **FFmpeg**, libdc1394, PGR FlyCapture, OpenKinect, videoInput, and ARToolKitPlus. I have done some work on ffmpeg in Javacv as I was not familiar with c/c++. It works great. Happy codding :)